# How to display Highest Price in Configurable Product on product page Magento 2

Tags: magento, configurable-product

How to display Highest Price in Configurable Product on product page Magento 2.
like i have one configurable product milk, it has two options/associated products 1Pcs and Carton, but in the product page system displays as low as the 1 Pcs price by default, I removed the as low as, bit i want to show the carton price by default